# Xcode pool drain?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

In Xcode 4.2, does `@autoreleasepool` replace `[pool drain];` and do I still need to allocate like so:

```
Person *Jay = [[Person alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 4):

This  `@ autoreleasepool { }` is equivalent to

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// Code benefitting from a local autorelease pool.
[pool release];
```

ARC still requires you to do either

```
[[NSString alloc] init]
```

or

```
[NSString string]
```

Under ARC there is no difference from the casual programmer perspective. Underneath, in the compiled code, the object returned by `[NSString string]` will go into a pool and later be released. The inited one will have a release inserted by the compiler just before it goes out of scope.

If you are not using ARC then you will later have to call `release` on the object returned by string.

Comment: It's somewhat misleading to suggest that you'll have to dealloc it; that might lead to newbies actually calling -dealloc directly, which is incorrect.

Comment: My bad, i meant release but realized that that part was wrong altogether under ARC. Old habits die hard.

Comment: I am just slightly confused, so my code goes inside @autoreleasepool{} do i still have to release the pool at the end of my code?

Comment: The code you want in your autoreleasepool goes between the curly braces. No you don't call release.

Comment: Although you can say that _conceptually_ `@autoreleasepool` is equivalent to `NSAutoreleasePool`, technically, it isn’t. In fact,  `@autoreleasepool` is faster than `NSAutoreleasePool`. Furthermore, keep in mind that `@autoreleasepool` is not ARC-specific.

Comment: Thank you all for the input, i have a better understanding and will research ARC as well

Comment: So if i am understanding correctly, under the newest Xcode 4.2 Arc is auto enabled. When i create an object i still need to alloc the object but i do not need to release said object since Arc covers this?

Comment: This would make total sense as to why when i tried `[pool drain];` at the end of my code (following an obvious older tutorial) i got an error, thank you all for your time and patience.

Comment: This is correct, you do not need to call release under ARC. In fact you cannot do so, the compiler will complain at you. Please accept my answer if it answered your question :)